# Displaying database content

Tags: php, database, mongodb

I'm trying to display the database 'hospitaldb', collection 'doctor' content using php. I've fields email, password, fname, lname in the collection. When I try to display these fields then I get error messages as :

Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpmongodb\viewdoctor.php on line 40

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpmongodb\viewdoctor.php on line 41

Notice: Undefined index: fname in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpmongodb\viewdoctor.php on line 42

Notice: Undefined index: lname in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpmongodb\viewdoctor.php on line 43

```
$server = "mongodb://localhost:27017/hospitaldb";
    try{
        $connection = new MongoDB\Client($server);
        /*$hospitaldb = $connection->test;*/
        $hospitaldb = $connection->hospitaldb;
    }catch (MongoConnectionException $ConErrMsg)
    {
        echo "$ConErrMsg";
    }

    $data = "<table style='border:1px solid red;";
    $data .= "border-collapse:collapse' border='1px'>";
    $data .= "<thead>";
    $data .= "<tr>";
    $data .= "<th>First Name</th>";
    $data .= "<th>Last Name</th>";
    $data .= "<th>Email</th>";
    $data .= "<th>Password</th>";
    $data .= "</tr>";
    $data .= "</thead>";
    $data .= "<tbody>";

    try{
        $db = $connection->hospitaldb;
        $collection = $db->doctors;
        $cursor = $collection->find();

        foreach ($cursor as $document)
        {
            $data .= "<tr>";
            $data .= "<td>" . $document["email"] . "</td>";
            $data .= "<td>" . $document["password"]."</td>";
            $data .= "<td>" . $document["fname"]."</td>";
            $data .= "<td>" . $document["lname"]."</td>";
            $data .= "</tr>";

        }

    }catch (MongoException $mongoException)
    {
        echo "$mongoException";
    }
```

Output :

```
object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)#20 (1) {
  ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=>
  array(5) {
    ["_id"]=>
    object(MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId)#16 (1) {
      ["oid"]=>
      string(24) "5ca746b2a930602fb8000e04"
    }
    ["email"]=>
    string(16) "sanekt@gmail.com"
    ["password"]=>
    string(6) "sanket"
    ["fname"]=>
    string(6) "sanket"
    ["lname"]=>
    string(6) "sanket"
  }
}


object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)#22 (1) {
  ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=>
  array(5) {
    ["_id"]=>
    object(MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId)#21 (1) {
      ["oid"]=>
      string(24) "5ca757fea930602fb8000e05"
    }
    ["email"]=>
    string(11) "p@gmail.com"
    ["password"]=>
    string(4) "7888"
    ["fname"]=>
    string(6) "piyush"
    ["lname"]=>
    string(4) "shah"
  }
}


object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)#16 (1) {
  ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=>
  array(5) {
    ["_id"]=>
    object(MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId)#20 (1) {
      ["oid"]=>
      string(24) "5ca8444aa9306032cc001a32"
    }
    ["email"]=>
    string(17) "shahsir@gmail.com"
    ["password"]=>
    string(7) "shahsir"
    ["fname"]=>
    string(4) "Shah"
    ["lname"]=>
    string(4) "Shah"
  }
}
```

Comment: Error is coming because what you are accessing from $document is not there. You may do var_dump($document); die; in loop and try to figure out.  If still can't then post the output here.

Comment: If I do var_dump($document) in for each loop, then I'm getting the contents.

Comment: Please put this in loop and then access data $document = $document->toArray(); please et us know if it works

Comment: check the indexes used in $document are match to the name of columns used in the database

Comment: They're correct.

Comment: Didn't get your point exactly. You're saying to put foreach loop data in $document = $document->toArray(); ? Is this what you're trying to say?

Comment: Yes, Sanket exactly

Answer (score 1):

The question you posted is working for me :

My setup :
php 7.2 thread safe
Downloaded DLL for windows from here https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb/1.5.3/windows. I put it in ext folder.

Composer.json

```
    "require": {
        "mongodb/mongodb": "^1.4"
    }
}
```

Executed php code from your post

```php
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
$server = "mongodb://localhost:27017/hospitaldb";
    try{
        $connection = new MongoDB\Client($server);
        /*$hospitaldb = $connection->test;*/
        $hospitaldb = $connection->hospitaldb;
    }catch (MongoConnectionException $ConErrMsg)
    {
        echo "$ConErrMsg";
    }

    $data = "<table style='border:1px solid red;";
    $data .= "border-collapse:collapse' border='1px'>";
    $data .= "<thead>";
    $data .= "<tr>";
    $data .= "<th>First Name</th>";
    $data .= "<th>Last Name</th>";
    $data .= "<th>Email</th>";
    $data .= "<th>Password</th>";
    $data .= "</tr>";
    $data .= "</thead>";
    $data .= "<tbody>";

    try{
        $db = $connection->hospitaldb;
        $collection = $db->doctors;
        $cursor = $collection->find();

        foreach ($cursor as $document)
        {
            $data .= "<tr>";
            $data .= "<td>" . $document["first_name"] . "</td>";
            $data .= "<td>" . $document["last_name"]."</td>";
            $data .= "</tr>";

        }

    }catch (MongoException $mongoException)
    {
        echo "$mongoException";
    }

    var_dump($data);
```